# Difference in rails 4 and rails 5 same code acting differently

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

I have this class in my rails 4, was working perfectly fine :

```
class Rule < ActiveModelSerializers::Model
  # Required by ActiveModelSerializers in order to seralize this object
  # @return [Hash] with all the attributes accessible for serialization
  def attributes
   ...some attributes...
  end

  def initialize(args = {})
    super
    @some_custom_variable = ...something...
  end
  # This method is relevant
  def assign_attributes(args)
    args.each { |k, v| instance_variable_set("@#{k}", v) }
    some_custom_variable.assign_attributes(args)
  end
end
```

This class is called from the controller create action like so:

```
rule = Rule.new(permitted_params.symbolize_keys)
rule.save
```

The problem I have is that `assign_attributes` is called when executing controller code (I know this because I've put breakpoint inside), this is just happening in rails 5.

So same code, same params in the controller (generated by same tests) behaves differently. And with rails 5, the code never ends up in `assign_attributes` method.

My question is why does it behave so with rails 5? Why does `assign_attributes` gets triggered?

Comment: What is that `assign_attributes` supposed to be doing?

Comment: `save` isn't  a method available on a serializer, is that a typo for the class name?

Comment: @Schwern apparently being used in update endpoint to assign attributes, I m not author of this code and am trying to handle transition to rails 5

Comment: @trueinViso `save` is not spelling mistake and yes it's not overriding original method, it's doing something app specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Rails 4, the [`assign_attributes` method](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.0.0/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeAssignment.html#method-i-assign_attributes) was part of ActiveRecord, in Rails 5 it is part of [ActiveModel](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/AttributeAssignment.html#method-i-assign_attributes). This change is mentioned in the [Rails5 CHANGELOG](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/5-0-stable/activemodel/CHANGELOG.md) which everyone reads prior to upgrading Rails.

Presumably, `ActiveModelSerializers::Model` includes an `assign_attributes` method via something in ActiveModel and something in ActiveModel thinks it is calling AM's `assign_attributes` rather than your accidental override.

However, the project is in a [state of chaos](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers#status-of-ams) (to be generous) so it is difficult to trace through the source:

> **Changes to 0.10.x maintenance:**
>
> - The 0.10.x version has become a huge maintenance version. We had hoped to get it in shape for a 1.0 release, but it is clear that isn't
>     going to happen. Almost none of the maintainers from 0.8, 0.9, or
>     earlier 0.10 are still working on AMS. We'll continue to maintain
>     0.10.x on the 0-10-stable branch, but maintainers won't otherwise be actively developing on it.
>
>   - We may choose to make a 0.11.x (
>       0-11-stable) release based on 0-10-stable that just removes the
>       deprecations.
>
> **What's happening to AMS:**
>
> - There's been a lot of churn around AMS since it began back in Rails 3.2 and a lot of new libraries are around and the JSON:API spec has reached 1.0.
> - If there is to be a 1.0 release of AMS, it will need to address the general needs of serialization in much the way ActiveJob can be used
>     with different workers.
> - The next major release is in development. We're starting simple and avoiding, at least at the outset, all the complications in AMS
>     version, especially all the implicit behavior from guessing the
>     serializer, to the association's serializer, to the serialization
>     type, etc.
> - ...

That was from six months ago and there is no useful code available on GitHub anymore, the project looks abandoned to me.

A short term fix would be to rename your `assign_attributes` method. A long term fix would be to replace ActiveModelSerializers altogether, preferable with something that is being actively maintained. The AMS README even offers [some alternatives](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers#alternatives):

> - [jsonapi-rb](http://jsonapi-rb.org/) is a highly performant and modular JSON:API-only implementation. There's a vibrant community around it that has produced projects such as JSON:API Suite.
> - [fast_jsonapi](https://github.com/Netflix/fast_jsonapi) is a lightning fast JSON:API serializer for Ruby Objects from the team of Netflix.

Comment: Agreed that ActiveModelSerializers is super fishy. For some reason they have removed all their code from `master` and only have it in branches. Weird. Though [ActiveModelSerializers doesn't define `assign_attributes`](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/search?q=assign_attributes&unscoped_q=assign_attributes), ActiveModelSerializers::Model [does include ActiveModel::Model](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/blob/0-10-stable/lib/active_model_serializers/model.rb).

Comment: @Schwern The "ActiveModelSerializers::Model does include ActiveModel::Model" part is almost certainly where the accidental `assign_attributes` override comes from. In the Rails4 version, `assign_attributes` only came from the OP's class so no one would call it unless the OP's code did; now that `assign_attributes` is part of ActiveModel, AM will be calling it. Hence the suggestion to use a different name while phasing out the whole AMS gem (which smells like a rotting corpse to me). Looking at `Method#owner` would be quick verification (provided AMS was installed).

Answer (score 0):

According to both the [Rails 4](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/AttributeAssignment/assign_attributes) and [Rails 5 docs](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/AttributeAssignment.html#method-i-assign_attributes), there's nothing about whether Rails itself will use `assign_attributes`. Just that it's a method you can use to assign a bunch of attributes at once.

Rails 4

> Allows you to set all the attributes by passing in a hash of attributes with keys matching the attribute names (which again matches the column names).

Rails 5

> Allows you to set all the attributes by passing in a hash of attributes with keys matching the attribute names.

`Rule.new` calling or not calling `Rule#assign_attributes` is a quirk of the implementation. It's not documented that `new` will call `assign_attributes` so you cannot rely on when Rails will call it.

In addition, if you've overriden `assign_attributes` it's important that it continue to do what it's documented to do. There should be no functional difference between setting each attribute individually and setting them all at once. It appears rather than call `super` you've written your own mass assignment code, and added your own extra code to mirror the attributes to another object.

There's also the question of how ActiveModelSerializers::Model might be interfering.

---

If you want to take action when a particular argument is set, instead override the associated `attribute=` method.

```
def foo=(value)
    ...
end
```

Or use the various [ActiveRecord::Callbacks](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html) such as `before_validation`.

Or since it appears you're trying to delegate the mass setting attributes, consider whether [delegation is the answer](https://api.rubyonrails.org/) instead.

```
delegate :this, :that, to: :some_custom_variable
```

Comment: I think the real issue is that `assign_attribute` used to be in ActiveRecord so it wouldn't end up being called by ActiveModel, now that method is part of ActiveModel so they have an accidental override.